# How to calculate dot product of array and every array on nested array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have and array x: `array([1,4,5])` and y: `array([[1,1,2], [4,2,1], [0,0,1]])`

I want to calculate dot product of x with every array in y. so output must shave shape of y. it must be:

`array([[15], [17], [5]])`

How to do that?

Comment: What happens when you use `numpy.dot(x, y)` or `numpy.dot(y, x)`?

Comment: `np.dot(y, x)[:, np.newaxis]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `matrix multiplication` operator introduced in [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/):

```
>>> y @ x
[15 17  5]
```

And resize it using `np.newaxis`:

```
>>> (y @ x)[:, np.newaxis]
[[15]
 [17]
 [ 5]]
```

This is synonymous to `np.dot`:

```
>>> np.dot(y, x)[:, np.newaxis]
[[15]
 [17]
 [ 5]]
```